# ASP.NET Compliler error Type exists in two dynamically compiled DLLs

Tags: asp.net

I've just gone thru a large-ish project and renamed A LOT of namespace directives.  Everything works fine on my developer box - deploy it to stage and I get:

`Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'ASP.usercontrols_pageheader_ascx' exists in both 
'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\89252a5f\7305b927\App_Web_hodsbmv3.dll' and '
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\89252a5f\7305b927\App_Web_pageheader.ascx.6bb32623.bs4iljip.dll'`

Yuck.  Very similar to this: [Deployment Project dlls cause ‘type x exists in both’ errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353721/deployment-project-dlls-cause-type-x-exists-in-both-errors), but must be coming from a different cause.

I have none of the problems I've seen mentioned in other articles (App_Code / CodeFile directive).  Worked out why it works on my machine: the website has no problem when it is in a vdir.  If I remove the "PageHeader" usercontrol from the masterpage it lives on everthing is fine.  <strike>If I rename "PageHeader" everything is fine</strike>. Updated: renaming the usercontrol doesn't help.

I'd had a look at the assemblies mentioned in the error in reflector; `App_Web_hodsbmv3.dll` contains dynamic classes for all the usercontrols in my project.  `\App_Web_pageheader.ascx.6bb32623.bs4iljip.dll'` contains the same code just for the PageHeader usercontrol.  Why would ASPX decide to create the same class in two assemblies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The winning answer goes to this forum post: [Publish web site: TYPE exists in both temporary ASP.NET assemblies](http://forums.asp.net/t/1249970.aspx)

> If you're getting this error, review all of the directive attributes and code-behind class names in your web user controls and web forms.

Because I'd changed all the namespaces in the project I'd botched in asmx.  I had an `Inherits` in the ASMX that didn't match the class in the code behind.  Somehow this resulted in the [compilation batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0.aspx) putting *some* (not all) usercontrols into their own temporary assemblies, AND the group assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using web deployment projects?

Try deleting the asp.net temporary directory for this application (located here: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\yourappname). You have to stop the app pool for this site before you delete the dir.

Try the setting to merge all outputs to a single assembly to see if it makes any difference.

..update..

"Merge to create a single assembly for all the Web UI content files by using Aspnet_merge.exe with the w option."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397866.aspx

Comment: I'm using a nant script to deploy (build it, copy the bin/ascx/aspx to the server). And I've already deleted the temp folders, gets recreated everytime.

Comment: have you restarted iis?  `iisreset /restart`

Comment: yes, restarted IIS.  restarted the apppool, deleted the temp assemblies.